# Visual studio Intellitrace Inner Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, intellitrace

I'm trying to debug an entity framework based application which uses a lot of await/async operations.

When some entity framework exception pops up, the intellitrace helps to find where is the problem, this is easy! The problem is that, the "locals window" doesn't show the inner exceptions, so, it's no possible to discovery the entity framework errors.

How to read inner exception from intellitrace?

Comment: Surely you have a logging mechanism in place that logs inner exceptions as well? I would look there first. Otherwise you might have bigger fish to fry.

Comment: To see the details of entity framework errors, you need to interact with inner exceptions, the intellitrace only shows the exceptions, not inner.